# My Youtube API Quota won't reset after 00:00 PST

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was writing a script to create  and fill playlists on my channel yesterday ( using playlist.insert and playlistItems.insert) when i received a 403 response with this message:

> "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your
>   \u003ca
>   href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e"

I think this is really strange because when i check my quota at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas  i'm way below my daily quota with only 32.554 queries (1 million is the daily limit). I decided to wait until midnight PST for my quota to reset but i still can't make requests.

Is there anything i can do to reset my quota?

Comment: Did you check if you are hitting your QPS per project or per user QPS? Also, have you tried visiting this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156953/youtube-quota-limit-exceeded-on-a-new-google-console-project?rq=1)?