# YouTube Quota Exceeded after 5 video uploaded

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I made simple YouTube uploader from this tutorial:

https://www.codexworld.com/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php/

After few uploaded videos I'm getting:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.quota",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e."
 }
}
```

What is wrong?

I tried to use this script:

https://codecanyon.net/item/youploader-url-to-youtube-video-uploader/22591259

And its works fine...

Comment: Did you make sure to use your *own* `oauthClientID` and `oauthClientSecret`?

Comment: Jake, Yes, I'm sure!

Comment: @JakeSteam, https://imgur.com/a/zEEigT4

Comment: Hmm okay, that makes my answer almost certainly irrelevant then. Sorry about that, I'll have a think.

Comment: Looks like others have had the same issue, with no luck... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349004/my-youtube-api-quota-wont-reset-after-0000-pst

Comment: @JakeSteam, if you need more screens let me know ;)

Comment: The only hint at a solution is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901102/608312, where the answer suggests double checking the key type.

Comment: @JakeSteam, but I using: https://imgur.com/a/yNT8vVZ

Answer (score 1):

Uploading videos is an extremely expensive action in terms of quota usage. An [approximate calculator is available](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), you are currently hitting your daily limits.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47409705/608312) suggests the limit is between 25-50 uploads per day (but file size may affect this, or it may be outdated information). You may be able to increase it by adding a payment method, joining a paid plan, or contacting Google.

It also appears that [different token types have different limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156953/youtube-quota-limit-exceeded-on-a-new-google-console-project), so make sure you are using an OAuth token not a playground token.